# Civi event links - Event Info-> 404 error

Tags: wordpress, civievent

I'm a newby just getting started and trying to learn how to set up events in Civi (5.6.0), using Wordpress (fresh install tester site).

In manage events, if I am looking at one of my events (which are saved, happy, and do show up via shortcodes on the Wordpress site) if I click 'event links' and then 'event info',  I get a 404 error. All the other event links open fine.

The URL it is trying to go to is this:
https://[myURL]/civicrm?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm/event/info&reset=1&id=4

Any idea how to get it to show the event page? Thanks!

Comment: Do you have a Base Page set in "Administer > System Settings > CMS Database Integration"? And does it exist in your list of Pages?

Comment: Thanks for asking! NO, that did return the 404 error. I changed the setting and it worked, YAY! Please explain: What does that setting do- does particular content need to be - or not be - on that page or other pages? Or feel free to point me toward documentation on it, I haven't found it

Comment: The page can be empty but it needs to be there. CiviCRM uses it to display forms on the front-end since the homepage (which CiviCRM used to use once upon a time) may not call `the_content()`. Lots of discussion here: https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bwordpress%5D+base+page

Comment: I'm going to add an answer that reflects this solution.

Comment: Perhaps you can mark my answer as the accepted answer? Will help others. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, total newbie- had to Google how to do that! OK, done, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a Base Page (if it doesn't exist) and enter its slug in CiviCRM by going to "Administer > System Settings > CMS Database Integration".